# Can I book a different accommodation after receiving my US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

I applied for a US visa and got it. During the application, I reserved some room in a hotel just to get a phone number and an address that I could use to fill the DS-160 form. After getting the visa I could find cheaper accommodation options in Airbnb and booked it after canceling my hotel room. Would that be a problem if the immigration officer asks where I will stay while entering the US?

Comment: I really doubt that this matters at all. As long as the address you give when you talk to him is correct, and there was no significant visa-related reason for the previous address (like someone living there agreed on paying your expenses), they wouldn't care which hotel you choose. I am not an immigration officer though, therefore this is not an 'answer', it just comes from a lot of experience.

Comment: The only situation where I can think this is likely to be a problem is if the change dramatically alters the purpose of your trip from when you applied for the visa. If your single entry visa was issued on the basis of a trip to attend a medical conference in New York and you now want to stay at a cabin in the woods in California, that could lead to some issues. But a different hotel in the same city should be just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Changing your hotel accommodations is no problem.

You only need to write the street address of your new accommodations on your landing card, which you will fill out on the plane and give to US immigration and customs officers. Make sure that you have the correct street address before you depart. (You'll also need it to give to your taxi driver.)

Answer (score 1):

The CBP doesn't have immediate access to what you wrote in the DS-160, because it's not relevant. A visa was issued, and all you need to do is fill out the blue form correctly (putting the new address on it) and answer the officer's questions truthfully.

Like Michael Hampton wrote, as long as your planned activities remain consistent with your visa, you'll be fine if otherwise deemed admissible by the officer you get.